# Use JobService in Android KitKat (4.4, API 19)

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, jobservice

Is there a way to use the JobService component and related components in an Android app with minSDK 19 (Android Kitkat, API level 19) ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkManager) replaced JobScheduler/JobService and you can use it from API level 14 and up.

But to answer you question specifically no, JobScheduler was add in api level 21